# Finding $P(Y > X)$ given $X\sim N(1,1)$ and $Y\sim N(2,2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution

> If $X\sim N(1,1)$ and $Y\sim N(2,2)$ are independent random variables,
>   find the value of $P(Y > X)$

Let $Z=Y-X$. Then

$P(Y\gt X)=P(Y-X \gt 0) =P(Z \gt 0) = 1-P(Z\leq 0)$

By linearity of expectation

$$\begin{align*}
E(Z)
&=E(Y-X)\\\\
&=E(Y)-E(X)\\\\
&=2-1\\\\
&=1
\end{align*}$$

By definition,

$$\begin{align*}
Var(Z)
&= Var(Y-X)\\\\
&= \left(1^2\right)Var(Y)+\left(-1^2\right)Var(X)\\\\
&= Var(Y)+Var(X)\\\\
&=1+2\\\\
&=3
\end{align*}$$

Thus I have

$$\begin{align*}
1-P(Z\leq 0)
&=1-\phi \left(\frac{0-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right) \\\\
&= 1-0.28197\\\\
&\approx .718
\end{align*}$$

Is this a valid solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a valid solution.

The whole idea is sum/ differences of independent normally distributed random variables are normally distributed random variables.

Credit: Michael Hardy for the correction.

Comment: I think it is valid. You can use the result for the [sum of two normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) directly. We have $Y\sim(2,2)$ and  $-X \sim N(-1,1)$ so $Y+(-X) = Z \sim N(2-1, 2+1)$.

Comment: "Sums of independent normal distributions are not normal distributions, but sums of independent normally distributed random variables are normally distributed random variables. In other words, what one adds is the random variables not the distributions.